# C# - Server-side Reflection/Dynamic Method Calling?

Tags: c#

This is probably coming off as a REALLY broad question.
But is there a way to have my applications code (or some of it) stored on a server, and download it and execute it securely?

I've been seeing ASP.net everywhere but I don't fully understand it. Is this basically exactly what im looking for, or is it some kind of C# Website Hosting, like xampp?

Either way, what im looking to do, is to be able to download some C# methods, not an entire namespace and be able to reference code like, System.*, Program, Form1 and such from those methods.

I managed to get CSHarpCodeProvider working and with System references using its CSharpParameter but it uses a direct namespace, essentially asking for an entire full valid .cs file, whereas I want to load in methods only and not have it secluded but to be interactable with all existing code.

This is probably a lot to ask and probably doesn't exist.

Here's my formula:

- Make a request to `website.com/api/login.php?e=email@domain.ext&p=Pass123`, returns obfuscated C# code along with the first line of text being an MD5 hash of the C# code, Email, Password and random generated strings/numbers/symbols.
- Generate the verification hash on the C# Client Side, send the returned hash back to the website on a different php script, That script will verify if it's correct and will return a session token even if it's an incorrect hash (meaning the request was tampered with).
- The C# returned from the first request, This seems good to go, Everything matches up. Replace the placeholder garbtext like `<!!TOKEN!!>` with the token from request 2 without doing verification checks at all.
- Execute the finalized C# code.
- The finalized C# code will do stuff like create methods that would be used throughout the application including a private bool x() that returns if the application is licenced/purchased.
- Use application as normal using the methods created.

Notes:

- Having some unixtime checks in the hash and inside bool x() and such would be a good idea to further prevent un-licenced intrusion.

Pros:

- The application is theoretically almost impossible to "Crack". To crack it, you would have to manually replace all the functions. Obfuscate the code on server-side before returning to the C# client and it will be extremely hard to do and would be very time consuming.
- Can be auto-updated and you wouldn't need to update the .exe unless you did vast changes.

Cons:

- Will require a lot more server power depending on the size of your userbase.
- Costs you and makes profit a lot smaller if your selling an application licence.
- Internet connection needed no-matter-what!
- Startup time would be slower.
- Downtime can seriously impact your application.

Comment: `The application is theoretically almost impossible to "Crack"` You sure about that?

Comment: No. Thats why I said almost impossible. There's obviously ways to still do it, but the amount of work needed would be a TON more work and will take WAY longer. You would literally need to re-implement all the methods manually in IL and have to de-obfuscate them if you added checks in the methods aswell. And of course, make the methods only work for that one single session only, Meaning if it was copy pasted (and all tokens still replaced) it wouldnt work, As it will do the checks and see they dont match up. If you see a flaw in my formula, advise me.

Comment: I think this is venturing into Security by Obscurity, and I feel that it violates Shannon's Maxim... 
In addition, the application would definitely be slower, since you're now dealing with variable network lag between function calls etc...

Have you considered using two languages like many video game engines do? You would utilize the first language to interpret the second (which is usually a scripting language).

Comment: @Catch44 Not sure what you mean. My application uses CEFSharp as a UI front and a lot of the UI values and buttons are executed via Javascript. But I think you mean, Have everything as C++ in a .dll and use that? No clue on C++ so thats kinda out the picture.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this would be used for? I believe your intent is -essentially- to send a client program one-time-use code, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Have considered storing small precompiled .Net dlls on the server instead of just plain C# code as a text? You can sign by the certificate these dlls, so the client knew they are valid.

Comment: @Catch44 Correct! Essentially a verification if email and password is correct, if it is, let them in download all the code, verify, and let the user use the application away. Otherwise kick them out. I have a TON of reasons why I dont just do normal if checks etc as this can SO easily be edited, Just do a brfalse on that IL and its bypassed. Trying to find various other methods of securing my application.

Comment: @SergeyL Honestly that could be easilly bypassed aswell. A dll can also be edited pretty easilly. Basically would be exactly the same but with worse start-time. Change a brtrue to a brfalse, done.

Comment: Final question; once they've downloaded the code, is there a need to delete that code afterwards, such as on log-out, or can it remain on the computer indefinitely?

Comment: You'll spend more time and effort implementing this feature than some guy will spend finding a workaround for it. One person with a license can capture the C# that gets compiled, and bake that into a DLL, and they've effectively got all that code you were trying to protect. That's not anywhere near "almost theoretically impossible." There are companies that spend all their time thinking about this problem space. If piracy is that big a concern, get a contract with one of them. Otherwise, I believe Visual Studio has some baked-in obfuscation tools that'll deter casual crackers.

Comment: Have you considered to simply create and use some kind of web service / web api, for example using WCF? IMHO all this sending, verifying, finalizing and executing C# code coming from the Internet sounds kind of creepy to me... If not implemented very carefully I think this could lead to a real security nightmare...

Comment: @Catch44 Would prefer for it to be memory based and not actually stored at all.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior As said, there would be checks inside the downloaded C# code, like unix timestamps, tokens, email-pass checks, etc.

Comment: Once the code is downloaded, those checks could be just as easily circumvented as if you had written those checks into the originally-installed code base. You're adding a lot of complexity just to create what's effectively a deferred code-loading scheme. Anyone with enough determination to overcome basic obfuscation is going to be able to get around this scheme just as easily, if not more so.

Comment: All this scheme is still quite easy to bypass, just edit the IL of the client-side to save the server-sent generated code to a permanent location and bypass the server entirely afterwards. As always, when you want to protect code from the user, the **ONLY** possible step is to never send the user the code. Instead, the "protected" code must live in a server of yours and the client send the input and receives the output. And in that situation, you're probably better off making a website rather than a normal program if you really want to avoid piracy.